# Invoke method on regular intervals using Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, threadpool, executorservice

I need to invoke a method on regular intervals without using the Timer class. That method will be invoked by multi threads.

Comment: Please provide more information. Ideally you could just invoke the method from each thread in a while loop having sleep between each iteration.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ExecutorService` like `ScheduledExecutorService` and its `scheduleAtFixedRate` method.

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
    ,0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    //initialDelay, period, unit
);

exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    () -> System.out.println("world"),
    500, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    //initialDelay, period, unit
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.sleep(milliseconds), where milliseconds is the interval in milliseconds.